# Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, compiler-errors

I'm getting the error:

> Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class

On the line:

```
public class LinqHelper
```

Here is the helper class, based on Mark Gavells code.  I'm really confused as to what this error means as I am sure it was working fine when I left it on Friday!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// Helper methods for link
/// </summary>
public class LinqHelper
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "OrderBy");
    }
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "OrderByDescending");
    }
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "ThenBy");
    }
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByDescending<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, string property)
    {
        return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "ThenByDescending");
    }
    static IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyOrder<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string property, string methodName)
    {
        string[] props = property.Split('.');
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        Expression expr = arg;
        foreach (string prop in props)
        {
            // use reflection (not ComponentModel) to mirror LINQ
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
            expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
            type = pi.PropertyType;
        }
        Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, arg);

        object result = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(
                method => method.Name == methodName
                        && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                        && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                        && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), type)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 377, accepted):

change

```
public class LinqHelper
```

to

```
public static class LinqHelper
```

Following points need to be considered when creating an extension method:

1. The class which defines an extension method must be *`non-generic`*, `static` and `non-nested`
2. Every extension method must be a `static` method
3. The first parameter of the extension method should use the `this` keyword.

Comment: If you have placed the class in App_Code then it is bound to have the static keyword in the class definition, but if you place it in any other folder then its fine to use it as normal class.

Comment: In one case, I had used `public static class IQueryable<T> where T : MyBaseClass` which also generates this error. The `where T : MyBaseClass` phrase belongs on the individual methods without `<T>` on the static class.

Comment: But what if the class is Partial? This solution did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I got caught on the "this" parameter!

Comment: Beware that you may get this compiler if you inadvertently converted your class to an extension method (according to the compiler). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921828/589259) with regards to static methods and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216538/589259) with regards to `this` method arguments.

Comment: If you didn't intend to have static methods, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216538/3437608) below as well!

Answer (score 100):

if you do not intend to have static functions just get rid of the "this" keyword in the arguments.

Comment: I was scratching my head for awhile trying to figure out why Visual Studio thought I was trying to make one of my classes an extension method. Turns out I had a `this` keyword buried in on of my method signatures. Removing it cleared the error.

Comment: This was the cause for me. The top answers don't explain why is it caused.

Comment: @Fütemire - I had same issue. I am suspicious that some auto-complete VS BS put it in there.

Comment: Same on me. On Copy-Paste I removed 'static' from the copied method forgetting to remove the **this** keyword in the parameters. The more 'this', the more CS1106.

Answer (score 24):

Add keyword `static` to class declaration:

```
// this is a non-generic static class
public static class LinqHelper
{
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Try changing

```
public class LinqHelper
```

to

```
 public static class LinqHelper
```

Answer (score 20):

A work-around for people who are experiencing a bug like Nathan:

The on-the-fly compiler seems to have a problem with this Extension Method error... adding `static` didn't help me either.

I'd like to know what causes the bug?

But **the work-around** is to write a new Extension class (not nested) even in same file and re-build.

Figured that this thread is getting enough views that it's worth passing on (the limited) solution I found.  Most people probably tried adding 'static' before google-ing for a solution! and  I didn't see this work-around fix anywhere else.

Comment: I had the same issue. I just realized that I added a static function within the class and forgot to comment it out. So that made my class static, and hence was giving this error. Check if there are any static objects in your class.

Answer (score 20):

I was scratching my head with this compiler error. My class was **not an extension method**, was working perfectly since months and needed to stay non-static. I had included a new method inside the class:

```
private static string TrimNL(this string Value)
{...}
```

I had copied the method from a sample and didn't notice the "this" modifier in the method signature, which is used in extension methods. Removing it solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks David! usually "this" fixes things, not breaks them.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly my problem. I was wonder what the hell?? Its the little things.

Answer (score 16):

Change it to

```
public static class LinqHelper
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this when converting a project to use dependency injection. If a method declaration contains the “this” keyword, VS will give the warning. In my case, I was able to remove “this” from all of the method declarations. If using “this” is required, you will have to make it static.

```
 public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property)
```

changed to

```
     public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string property)
```

You might need to code around not using the “this” keyword for the method declaration if you want to avoid using a static class with static methods. If “this” is only required for some methods, those methods can be moved to a separate public static class.

Answer (score 1):

Extension method should be inside a static class.
So please add your extension method inside a static class.

so for example it should be like this

```
public static class myclass
    {
        public static Byte[] ToByteArray(this Stream stream)
        {
            Int32 length = stream.Length > Int32.MaxValue ? Int32.MaxValue : Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            return buffer;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is this different from the answers given years before?

Comment: It's from a different author 

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to static class and back. That might resolve visual studio complaining when it's a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, I created a 'foo' folder and created a "class" inside foo, then I get the aforementioned error. One fix is to add "static" as earlier mentioned to the class which will be "public static class LinqHelper".

My assumption is that when you create a class inside the foo folder it regards it as an extension class, hence the following inter alia rule apply to it:

1) Every extension method must be a static method

WORKAROUND If you don't want static.
My workaround was to create a class directly under the namespace and then drag it to the "foo" folder.