# Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have written the following code  to find out the missing sequence but i am getting the error as i mentioned this is my code

```
public partial class Missing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> daysOfMonth =
       new List<int>() { 6, 2, 4, 1, 9, 7, 3, 10, 15, 19, 11, 18, 13, 22, 24, 20, 27, 31, 25, 28 };
    Response.Write("List of days:");
    foreach (var num in daysOfMonth)
    {
        Response.Write(num);
    }
    Response.Write("\n\nMissing days are: ");
    // Calling the Extension Method in the List of type int 
    foreach (var number in daysOfMonth.FindMissing()){Response.Write(number);}
}
public static IEnumerable<int> FindMissing(this List<int> list)
{
    // Sorting the list
    list.Sort();
    // First number of the list
    var firstNumber = list.First();
    // Last number of the list
    var lastNumber = list.Last();
    // Range that contains all numbers in the interval
    // [ firstNumber, lastNumber ]
    var range = Enumerable.Range(firstNumber, lastNumber - firstNumber);
    // Getting the set difference
    var missingNumbers = range.Except(list);
    return missingNumbers;
}
```

}

I am getting the error as follows `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class` can any one help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096299/extension-methods-must-be-defined-in-a-non-generic-static-class)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the error states, extension methods can only be declared on a non-generic static class. You are attempting to declare the `FindMissing` method in the `Missing` class, which is not a non-generic static class.

You have two options:

1. Make the method a normal method, in which case it can stay in the `Missing` class
2. Declare another class, perhaps `MissingExtensions`, to contain the method

This is what the second option would look like:

```
public static class MissingExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> FindMissing(this List<int> list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error if i write as per you said `Extension method must be defined in a top level static class; MissingExtensions is a nested class`

Comment: @Chaitanya You didn't write it as he said; he said nothing about nesting it inside the outer class.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you have to write as per `Bryan watts` answer

```
public partial class Missing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Your code
}
}

public static class MissingExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> FindMissing(this List<int> list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```