# generic method to create a copy of any collection (with matching type)

Tags: c#, collections, interface, copy, generic-programming

I am looking for a way to create a new collection from an old one, that contains the same elements.

For `HashSet<T>` it works like this:

```
HashSet<T> oldSet = ... // consider it filled with elements
HashSet<T> newSet = new HashSet<T>(oldSet);
```

For `List<T>` it is analogous:

```
List<T> oldList = ... // consider it filled with elements
List<T> newList = new List<T>(oldList);
```

As far as I know, all `ICollection<T>` implementations have this type of copy constructor.

**Is there a method (let's call it `CreateCopy` for now) that does this for all `ICollection<T>`?** So that I can call it like this?

```
ICollection<T> oldColl = ... // can be List, HashSet, ...
ICollection<T> newColl = oldColl.CreateCopy(); // will have the same type as oldColl
```

**If not, how can I write my own method to achieve this?** The only idea that comes to my mind looks like this:

```
public static ICollection<T> CreateCopy<T>(this ICollection<T> c)
{
    if (c is List<T>) return new List<T>(c);
    else if (c is HashSet<T>) return new HashSet<T>(c);
    else if ...
}
```

but of course this is a horrible solution - whenever a new implementation of `ICollection<T>` comes around, I need to update that method...

Comment: Btw, you can't create generic extension methods

Comment: @MetaColon Yes I can. The method `CreateCopy` compiles with no errors when I replace the last line `else if ...` by e.g. `else return null;`

Comment: I don't know how you managed to this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238156/7700150

Comment: @MetaColon Then just try it out with a current C# version. That question is 5 years old...

Comment: @MetaColon Of course you can create generic extension methods. LINQ for instance is built on generic extension methods. What you mean is that the static class in which you declare extension methods can't be generic. The methods can be.

Comment: @Kjara Nothing about that answer has changed in the past 5 years, as Dennis explains, it is simply irrelevant.

Comment: It can't be done except with reflection.

Comment: @Dennis_E my wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One option to do it without reflection is this:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static TCollection CreateCopy<TCollection, TItem>(this TCollection c) where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>, new() {
        var copy = new TCollection();
        foreach (var item in c) {
            copy.Add(item);
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

This has the following benefits:

- Type-safe. Cannot pass instance of `ICollection<T>` that does not have parameterless constructor (and there are such implementations).
- No reflection.
- Returns the same type you passed in (so `HashSet<T>` if you passed `HashSet<T>`, not generic `ICollection<T>`).

Drawbacks:

- Major one is syntax you have to use to call it:

  ```
  var set = new HashSet<string>();
  // have to specify type arguments because they cannot be inferred
  var copy = set.CreateCopy<HashSet<string>, string>();
  ```
- Cannot pass interface (`ICollection<T>` itself) - should pass concrete class (`HashSet<T>`, `List<T>` etc).

Answer (score 0):

If it implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can use an identity projection:

```
var copy = myEnumerable.Select(item => item);
```

Of course, this is only a shallow copy, if `T` is a reference type, you will only be copying the reference, therefore both enumerables will be pointing to the same objects.

Also, you loose the specialization of the orignal enumerable, but that can't be avoided unless you actually write an overload for all expected collections.

Comment: Do you know if, in case `myEnumerable` implements `ICollection<T>`, the cast `(ICollection<T>)myEnumerable.Select(item => item)` is safe?

Comment: @Kjara No, that won't work, as you can see by just running the code and seeing the exception get thrown.

Comment: @Kjara No, an `ICollection<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` but it doesn't go the way around; not any `IEnumerable<T>` is an `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

There actually are three possible ways to do this:

```
public static ICollection<T> CreateCopyReflection<T> (this ICollection<T> c)
{
    var n = (ICollection<T>) Activator.CreateInstance (c.GetType());
    foreach (var item in c)
        n.Add (item);
    return n;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> CreateCopyLinq<T> (this IEnumerable<T> c) => c.Select (arg => arg);

public static IEnumerable<T> CreateCopyEnumeration<T> (this IEnumerable<T> c)
{
    foreach (var item in c)
        yield return item;
}
```

Note that we can use IEnumerables here without worrying, as `ICollection<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`.

The first solution creates a copy using reflection, the second one using Linq and the third one using enumeration. We can now profile this with the following code:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range (0, 100000000).ToList();
var trueCopy = new List<int> (myList);
var time = Environment.TickCount;
var copyOne = myList.CreateCopyReflection();
Console.WriteLine($"Refelection copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
time = Environment.TickCount;
var copyTwo = myList.CreateCopyLinq ();
Console.WriteLine ($"Linq copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
time = Environment.TickCount;
var copyThree = myList.CreateCopyEnumeration ();
Console.WriteLine ($"Enumeration copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
time = Environment.TickCount;
```

Which results in:

```
Reflection copy: 1375
Linq copy: 0
Enumeration copy: 0
```

However, we have to keep in mind that c# is lazy here, which means that it didn't actually calculate the values, so we only get comparable results when enumerating the IEnumerables:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range (0, 100000000).ToList();
var trueCopy = new List<int> (myList);
var time = Environment.TickCount;
var copyOne = myList.CreateCopyReflection().ToList();
Console.WriteLine($"Reflection copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
time = Environment.TickCount;
var copyTwo = myList.CreateCopyLinq ().ToList();
Console.WriteLine ($"Linq copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
time = Environment.TickCount;
var copyThree = myList.CreateCopyEnumeration ().ToList();
Console.WriteLine ($"Enumeration copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
time = Environment.TickCount;
```

Which results in:

```
Reflection copy: 1500
Linq copy: 1625
Enumeration copy: 3140
```

So we can see that the enumeration is the slowest, followed by linq and then reflection. However, reflection and linq are very close and linq has the huge (at least in a lot of cases) advantage that it's lazy (as well as the enumeration), which is why I'd use it.

---

It's quite interesting to compare to if cascades:

```
private static void Main ()
{
    var myList = Enumerable.Range (0, 100000000).ToList();
    var trueCopy = new List<int> (myList);
    var time = Environment.TickCount;
    var copyOne = myList.CreateCopyReflection().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"Reflection copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
    time = Environment.TickCount;
    var copyTwo = myList.CreateCopyLinq ().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine ($"Linq copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
    time = Environment.TickCount;
    var copyThree = myList.CreateCopyEnumeration ().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine ($"Enumeration copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
    time = Environment.TickCount;
    var copyFour = myList.CreateCopyCascade ();
    Console.WriteLine($"Cascade copy: {Environment.TickCount - time}");
    time = Environment.TickCount;

    Console.ReadLine ();
}

public static ICollection<T> CreateCopyReflection<T> (this ICollection<T> c)
{
    var n = (ICollection<T>) Activator.CreateInstance (c.GetType());
    foreach (var item in c)
        n.Add (item);
    return n;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> CreateCopyLinq<T> (this IEnumerable<T> c) => c.Select (arg => arg);

public static IEnumerable<T> CreateCopyEnumeration<T> (this IEnumerable<T> c)
{
    foreach (var item in c)
        yield return item;
}

public static ICollection<T> CreateCopyCascade<T> (this ICollection<T> c)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(List<T>))
        return new List<T> (c);
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(HashSet<T>))
        return new HashSet<T> (c);
    //...
    return null;
}
```

Which results in:

```
Reflection copy: 1594
Linq copy: 1750
Enumeration copy: 3141
Cascade copy: 172
```

So we can see that the cascade is way faster - however, it won't work if other collections are created which derive from ICollection, as it won't know them, so this solution isn't very advisable.