# How to solve 'Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im pretty new to C# and got myself a project from a friend and I'm having this error when I'm trying to compile it:

> `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
```

Probably a very simple problem but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Is your intention to add an extension method or by mistake you added this keyword in method parameter? If latter, just drop the this keyword from parameter, if former then [do what compiler says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096299/extension-methods-must-be-defined-in-a-non-generic-static-class)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to define an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx) in that class.

An extension method is marked with the `static` modifier and its first argument with the `this` modifier, e.g.:

```
public static void Method(this string arg) {}
```

If you added the `this` modifier by mistake, simply remove it to make it a normal static method.
If you did it on purpose, move the method declaration to a static non-generic non-nested class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's telling you exactly what's wrong - you can't put an extension method (a static method whose first parameter is preceded by `this`) in anything other than a non-generic static class. Look for a method (or methods) where the first parameter is preceded by `this`, and move them to a new, non-generic static class:

```
public static class SomeExtensions
{
    // Extension methods go here, e.g.
    public static void SomeMethod(this SomeClass firstParam, int secondParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `this` keyword in a method signature, indicating it is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

You should create a `static` class to contain those methods. The signature must be something like this:

```
public static class PageExtensionMethods
{
    public static void SomeMethod(this SomeType s)
    { }
}
```

Make sure though, you really intent to use extension methods. If it is just a method you want to call, it doesn't really have to be an extension method. Remove the `this` keyword then.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as complier wants it *should be done*:

```
  // Public static non generic class (exactly what compiler wants)
  public static class PageExtensions {
    ...
    // Your extension method for System.Web.UI.Page
    public static void MyExtensionMethod(this System.Web.UI.Page value) {
      ...
    }
  }
```